# hide empty spaces below and above the block

Tags: html, css

please visit [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)

you can see following image in the link :

[image]

there are lot of empty spaces below and above that image. i want to remove those gap and i want to display like [link2](http://test.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)

```
.check_delivery .actions {float: left;width: 25%;}
.check_delivery .f-right {margin-left: 0 !important;}
.check_delivery .f-right, .right {float: left !important;}
.check_delivery .button > span {background: #565656 none repeat scroll 0 0; width: 100% !important;}
.check_delivery .button span {padding: 3px;text-transform: capitalize !important;}
.check_delivery .item.last.odd { padding: 0;}

.check_delivery .search {margin: 0 auto !important; width: 100%;}

.check1 {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.ikon {
    position: relative;
    top:50px;
}

.check_delivery .block-subtitle {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-family: Museo,Helvetica,arial,san-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  width: 27%;
}
.check_delivery #estimate_postcode {

    float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-left: 10px !important;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px !important;
  width: 70% !important;

}


.shipping-estimation-form {

    float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 30%;
}
```

i tried this :

```
.block block-shipping-estimate
{  position : relative; bottom:70px; }
```

but i think its going to effect on other part of the page.

can anyone help me for some proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change below css

```
.ikon {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  /*position: relative;
  top: 50px;*/
}

.block, .sidebar .box-reviews {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 96%;
}

.short-description .std ul { margin: 0; }

.check_delivery .block-subtitle {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   font-family: Museo,Helvetica,arial,san-serif;
   font-size: 15px;
   margin-top: 6px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   width: 26%;
}

.product-view .add-to-box {
  margin-top: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.div_link-cart .block-cart-top {
  clear: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 0 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: i tried , now more gap is displaying between "search bar" & " "menu",

before it was displaying like this : [link](http://test.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)

Comment: on top  , next to "search" box,  there is no cart button is displaying. in another link its displaying

Comment: also above "Check Availabilty at" text, there are 2 lines displaying , please help me to remove one line &

display as like [here](http://test.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)

Comment: for dispaying "cart " text on top, i removed  `width: 96%;` from  `.block, .sidebar .box-reviews` . now "Check Availabilty at" is displaying in 2 lines

Answer (score 1):

Do following will remove some extra spaces from below and top.

Remove `margin: 0 0 30px; padding: 10px 20px 20px;` from `.block, .sidebar .box-reviews` and give `position: relative;` to it.

Change `ikon` css like:

```
.ikon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}
```

And remove `<br>` from `.short-description` and `.std`.

[image]

Comment: i tried your code, buts it hide the "ADD to cart" & "Buy now" button. : prnt.sc/aivwu0

Comment: @Profile101 remove `overflow:hidden` from `.product-view .add-to-box`

Comment: also above "Check Availabilty at" text, there are 2 lines displaying , please help me to remove one line &

display as like [here](http://test.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)

Comment: @Profile101 remove `<hr class="hr">`

Comment: last problem, on top , next to "search" box, there is no cart text is displaying. in another [link](http://test.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-nx0-small.html) its displaying.
even i need gap between "cart" button & menu.

Comment: @Profile101 last solution.  remove `width: 96%;` from `.block, .sidebar .box-reviews`

Comment: once i remove `width: 96%;` "Check Availabilty at" is displaying in 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the same DOM and CSS classes like in the second link?

```
<div class="block-content"> <div id="block_info">
    <img src="http://totaltoys.com/media/font-100.png" height="35" width="70"> 
    <strong><span>Check Delivery Availability</span></strong>       
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text" maxlength="120" id="zipcode" size="20" name="zipcode" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}">
    <button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button1" id="zip-check"><span>CHECK</span></button>
    <div id="delivery-message"></div>
    <div id="delivery-html"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

In addition my suggestion is to use Angular directives: [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

This is a great solution in such cases that a template is repeated many times in your code.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it just add padding as you need it!

```css
#label{
    height: auto;
    float: left;
  
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 50px;
  
    background-image: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simple-microphone-icon/512/Location_Icon-128.png");
    background-position: left top;
    background-size: 45px 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#check{
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
}
#keyword-boxer{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 2.5px;
}
#keyword{
    width: 98.75%;
    height: 36px;
  
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label id="label">Check Availability</label>
    <button id="check">Check</button>
  
    <div id="keyword-boxer"><input type="text" id="keyword"/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    .block.block-shipping-estimate {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        clear: both;
        position:relative;
    }
    .ikon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `position: relative` for both following classes and then set

```
margin:0px !important;
padding: 0px !important;
width : 100%;
```

**Here is the html Code:**

```
.block.block-shipping-estimate {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.block, .sidebar .box-reviews {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```